# tokenizing the data properly in gensim

Tags: python, gensim

I am a bit confused as how to tokenize the data correctly in `gensim`.
I have a text file  `myfile.txt` that contains the following text

```
""" 
this is a very long string with a title


and some white space. Multiple sentences, too. This is nuts!
Yay! :):):) 
"""
```

I load this file in `gensim` using `LineReader('myfile.txt')` to train a `word2vec` model (of course my data is much bigger than the example above)

But is this text tokenized propertly? I am asking this because `LineReader` seems to be very specific :

> The format of files (either text, or compressed text files) in the
> path is one sentence = one line, with words already preprocessed and
> separated by whitespace.
> see https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence

I am confused. Am I doing things right? How should I tokenize my text for `LineReader`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work, but because Gensim's `LineSentence` class (what I assume you mean) breaks tokens on whitespace, your line...

```
and some white space. Multiple sentences, too. This is nuts!
```

...will become the list of word-tokens:

```
['and', 'some', 'white', 'space.', 'Multiple', 
'sentences,', 'too.', 'This', 'is', 'nuts!']
```

That means tokens like `'space.'`, `'sentences,'`, & `'nuts!'` will be treated as words – potentially even receiving trained word-vectors, too (if they appear at least `min_count` times).

That's probably not what you want – but also not necessarily a big problem. In a sufficiently-large corpus, all the words you care about will appear so many times without this connected-punctuation issue, you'll probably still get good vectors for them.

But more typically, you'd preprocess your text to either strip that punctuation, or split it off from words with extra space delimiter characters. (When you do that, the punctuation marks themselves become 'words' of a sort.)

Comment: thank you, very useful! Just a follow up then? Can I use `Phrases()` on `LineSentence` like `sent = LineSentence('myfile.txt'); bigrams = Phrases(sent)`When I do so the computation takes a lot of time (I imagine `Phrases()` needs to see all the text to compute the bigrams). But it seems `gensim` needs again a lot of time when calling `word2vec(bigrams[sent])`. is that expected? Thanks!

Comment: `Phrases` can work on the same style of corpus – iterable of lists-of-words – that `Word2Vec` accepts, yes. `Phrases` requires a full survey of word occurrences & co-occurrences – one full pass over hte corpus, & lots of memory – to be ready to do bigram-combinations on further passes.

Comment: Doing the bigram-combo calcs on each future pass also requires re-calculations - you could look into the `FrozenPhrases` class (which slims the RAM & caches the bigram-decisions of `Phrases` for repeated application), or consider writing the output of `bigrams[sent]` to its own plain-text file - so you can both examine its results, and conduct future re-trainings from the plain text, without even needing a `Phrases`/`FrozenPhrases` instance in the loops. (It finishes its job, writes the changed corpus, & then is done.)

Comment: super useful!! thanks @gojomo. so you mean I could write the output of `bigrams[sent]` to a text file of its own, so that I can call `LineSentence` on this file directly? But I thought `LineSentence` required tokens, not bigrams? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yes, youd take each list-of-tokens from `bigrams[sent]` - which will be a mix of the original tokens, and those combined by the `Phrases` model – and re-join them with delimiting spaces, and write those, line-by-line, to a file. Then you have a file you can examine - or use against with `LineSentence` (which takes a file with space-delimited lines of text).